# c++ Unique pointer with custom deleter error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to make a wrapper class with an unique pointer with a custom deleter. This is the class:

```
class WindowObj
{
    public:
        WindowObj();
        WindowObj(const WindowObj&) = delete;
        WindowObj& operator=(const WindowObj&) = delete;
        WindowObj(WindowObj&&);
        WindowObj& operator=(WindowObj&&);
        WindowObj(const char* title,int x,int y,const int& w,const int& h,SDL_WindowFlags flags);
        SDL_Window* get();
    protected:
    private:
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window,decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)> window;
};
WindowObj::WindowObj(const char* title,int x,int y,const int& w,const int& h,SDL_WindowFlags flags)
{
    window = make_resource(SDL_CreateWindow,SDL_DestroyWindow,title,x,y,w,h,flags);
}


SDL_Window* WindowObj::get(){
    return window.get();
}

WindowObj::WindowObj(){
    window = NULL;
}

WindowObj::WindowObj(WindowObj&& other){
    std::swap(window,other.window);
}

WindowObj& WindowObj::operator=(WindowObj&& other){
    std::swap(window,other.window);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to compile this I get the error `error: static assertion failed: constructed with null function pointer deleter`. Using a shared_ptr instead fixes the problem, but I may not need sharing the pointer. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't initializing `window`, you're assigning to it after it is first default-constructed (with a null deleter, hence the error).

You need to use the member initializer list to actually *initialize* it:

```
WindowObj::WindowObj(const char* title,int x,int y,const int& w,const int& h,SDL_WindowFlags flags)
: window(make_resource(SDL_CreateWindow,SDL_DestroyWindow,title,x,y,w,h,flags))
{
}
```

(Assuming `make_resource` returns a `unique_ptr` and passes the 2nd argument to its constructor.)

Comment: The make_resource function is from https://eb2.co/blog/2014/04/c-plus-plus-14-and-sdl2-managing-resources/

Answer (score 1):

You have never passed SDL_DestroyWindow to window (to the unique_ptr itself, not its contents).
Try

```
WindowObj::WindowObj(const char* title,int x,int y,const int& w,const int& h,SDL_WindowFlags flags)
    : window(make_resource(SDL_CreateWindow,SDL_DestroyWindow,title,x,y,w,h,flags), &SDL_DestroyWindow) {}
```

Comment: Aha, you don't need to add second argument to window(), make_resource handles this. As pointed out before, if make_resource() is called from inside the {} brackets, first it is default-constructed, and then it is assigned to.